# Problem with run net core app on Ubuntu 16.08

Tags: c#, .net, ubuntu

I am trying to start a chat bot written in net core 2.1 on a Ubuntu 2.1 machine. But the application does not want to start on the following problem:

[image]

This is what my csproj file looks like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
      <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <StartupObject></StartupObject>
    <ApplicationIcon />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Net.Code.ADONet" Version="4.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SQLite" Version="1.0.111" />
    <PackageReference Include="xNet" Version="3.3.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Win32.Registry" Version="4.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Well, the error message is pretty clear, you can't use windows specific library for work with registry on linux

Answer (score -1):

Fixed the problem.
I used "publishing" through a visual studio, and this caused this problem.
Using the dotnet console solves this problem.